# Animation in Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I created an Angular Sidebar by using a SidebarService [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mt5ikd):

```
export class SidebarService {
  public hidden: boolean = true;
  toggle(): void {
    this.hidden = !this.hidden;
  }
}
```

Then I have a Sidebar component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './sidebar.component.css' ]
})

export class SidebarComponent {

  constructor(public sidebarService: SidebarService) { }

}
```

Which template is:

```
<div id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{'hidden': sidebarService.hidden}">

  <button type="button" (click)="sidebarService.toggle()">
    Close Sidebar
  </button>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Finally I use it as follows:

```
<sidebar></sidebar>

<button type="button" (click)="sidebarService.toggle()">
  Open Sidebar
</button>

<h1>Main Content</h1>
```

**Questions**

1. Instead of Hide/Show the sidebar is it possible to slide it from left?
2. Is using a service a good approach to share the hide/show the side bar in different places?
   Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of Hide/Show the sidebar is it possible to slide it from left?**

You can use angular animation for `ngIf` toggle instead of `hidden` class.

```
<div *ngIf="!sidebarService.hidden" id="sidebar" [@anim]="sidebarService.hidden">
```

and ts file:

```
animations: [
    trigger('anim', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
        animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngz5em)